# Trouble creating a new file

Tags: c, file-io

I have a simple line in my C++ code to create a new file:

```
string fileName = "test";

// Create a file named "test"
rc = pf->CreateFile(fileName.c_str());
```

---

Inside `CreateFile` function (which takes `const char *fileName` as an argument, I have following snippet of code;

```
// Create the file in current working directory
char *path = NULL;
path = getcwd(path, 0);
path = strcat(path, "/");
path = strcat(path, fileName);
FILE *fHandle = fopen(path, "wb");
```

The string `path` contains full absolute path of the file to be created. The file name is `test`. However when I run the code, the file is indeed created, however its name contains unprintable characters (code was run between following two commands):

[image]

Please suggest what could be wrong.

Comment: show the code which set `path`. btw this is c, not c++

Comment: How are you setting the `path` variable in your code?  Is it a hard-coded path, are you prompting the user, or passing it as an argument?

Comment: @UmNyobe is right. You problem is in block that set path. You have some junk in this variable.

Comment: @Ryan: I edited my code to include the portion that sets `path`.

Comment: yep... but I guess you need to show also how do you set `fileName` :P

Comment: As @Ryan points out, why not just `fopen(fileName)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [man getcwd](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd):

> As an extension to the POSIX.1-2001 standard, Linux (libc4, libc5, glibc) getcwd() allocates the buffer dynamically using malloc(3) if buf is NULL. In this case, the allocated buffer has the length size unless size is zero, when buf is allocated as big as necessary. The caller should free(3) the returned buffer.

This means there is no extra space left in `path` to be appending to and results in overwriting the bounds of the array that `path` points to, causing undefined behaviour and is the probable cause of the unprintable characters.

To construct a buffer capable of holding the path you need to determine the full size, `malloc()` and build it:

```
char *path;
path = getcwd(path, 0);
if (path)
{
    /* The '+2' is for null terminator and the '/'. */
    const size_t size = strlen(path) + strlen(fileName) + 2;
    char* fullPath = malloc(size);
    if (fullPath)
    {
        sprintf(fullPath, "%s/%s", path, fileName);
        /* fopen() ... */
        free(fullPath);
    }
    free(path);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `fopen()` look in the current working directory by default anyway?  This seems like a lot of work to do when you could just pass in `fileName` to `fopen()`.

Comment: @Ryan, good point and yes. However, this was the cause of the unprintables but just using `fopen(fileName)` is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Your `path` variable probably doesn't end by `\0`.